# Mysql: searching through all rows with equal values in one colum

Tags: mysql, search

I'm trying to `select all rows` that contain the same value in one column and search the selected rows.
For example:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
cool    4       55      0       1/2/1999
peeps   3       44      4       12/15/2010
great   4       23      1       3/4/2002
ok      5       12      5       4/27/2003
huh     4       25      7       5/16/2004
```

I have to search for a specific value within the rows, in this case I would be selecting rows in column 2 with the value of 4. Then searching those rows for dates.

Comment: What results are you looking for? The dates for all rows where column 2 equals 4?

Comment: yes i need to search those dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all dates where column2 = 4:

```
select column5 from table where column2 = 4
```

If you want to also restrict by a date range:

```
select * from table where column2 = 4 and column5 >= '1999-01-02' and column5 <= '2004-05-16'
```

Comment: so, once i select column5 from table where column2 = 4 how would i search for the dates?

Comment: Define 'search for the dates'. What exactly do you want to search for?

Comment: for example: i would want to search the rows equal to 4 for dates between 1/1/1999 and 4/28/2003 and display those days.

Comment: That's almost identical to my answer:

`select column5 from table where column2 = 4 and column5 >= '1999-01-01' and column5 <= '2003-04-28'`

Comment: cool. ok. this is what i have at the moment 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE s_date = '$theDate'", $connect);

Comment: You should be able to adapt what I've posted for that table. Without providing more information about how that table is structured, what data it contains, and what records you're trying to find, we'd be shooting in the dark.